# Not able to get the saved data bytes when reading the same file

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata, writetofile

I am writing **NSMutableData** to image file using **writeToFile** with the below code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"binaryData.jpg"];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData alloc];
[data appendData:rawData]; 
[data writeToFile:file atomically:NO];

NSLog (@"Data Length: %d.",data.length); 

// Data Length: 30506
```

I am reading the saved image file with the below code.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    UIImage *selectedImageFile = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *PNGData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageFile)];
    NSData *JPEGData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImageFile, 1.0)];

    NSURL *imageURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(asset.defaultRepresentation.size);
        NSUInteger k = [asset.defaultRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset: 0.0 length:asset.defaultRepresentation.size error:nil];
        rawData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:k freeWhenDone:YES];  

    }

    NSLog (@"PNG Length: %d.", PNGData.length); // PNG Length: 78101
    NSLog (@"JPEG Length: %d.", JPEGData.length); // JPEG Length: 37548
    NSLog (@"Raw Data Length: %d.", PNGData.length); // Raw Data Length: 34163


}
```

If you see the above code, My source data length is '30506' before sending it to **writeToFile**.

But I am not able to get the same bytes while reading the same image with **UIImagePickerController**.

I tried with **UIImagePNGRepresentation**, **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** and **ALAssetsLibrary**. But I am not able to get the same bytes in any of my trials.

Can somebody guide me how to save/get the same bytes?

Comment: This looks dodgy: `[NSMutableData alloc];`.  Add the `init` call and see if it makes any difference.  However why are you even creating that `NSMutableData` given you already have the data as an `NSData` object (`[data appendData:rawData];`)?

Comment: I will append more NSData objects later on. That is the reason i have declared NSMutableData. I tried your option but no difference.